# iPhone SDK - CCATS required if using Keychain Access?

Tags: iphone, encryption, keychain

I'm planning on using Keychain in an iPhone app to store some username/password information. Am I still required to file for an CCATS?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you use the crypto libraries already available in the iPhone SDK, then no, you will not need a CCATS. Technically any encryption exporting will be Apple's encryption code and so you should be free and clear.

Check out [Lamarche's post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html) on this topic for more information.

Comment: Nope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption