# ShareKit encryption app submission

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, sharekit

I am using sharekit in my app and now I am ready to upload my app to iTunes Connect. My question is:

In "Export Compliance", I am asked if my app uses encryption, and since I am using sharekit and it deals with Twitter and Facebook passwords, should I check that I am using encryption or not? If yes, what kind is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ShareKit shouldn't require answering yes to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are using encryption! You are using HTTPS, HMAC and various other technologies through ShareKit. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption) for discussion of these requirements. There are a series of questions after that one which determine whether you need further paperwork.