# What to prepare before submitting an app to AppStore with encryption?

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, app-store

I am going to submit an app with encryption to AppStore. The app `CCCrypt` and stores text files in the iPhone, using `<CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>` by Apple.

I will mostly likely select "Yes" when [Apple asks if my app contains encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption).

Is there anything I should prepare besides the above declaration?

p.s. I am *not* a US citizen or resident.

Comment: Just for the record: If you lived in the US and you used other than Apple's embedded encryption you'd (in theory) need to clear it with the government.

Answer (score 3):

I recently submitted an application that uses CommonCrypto as well.  I only selected "YES".  There was no followup from Apple on the topic.  It was accepted to the AppStore.

Comment: What encryption algorithm did you use in your application??

Comment: AES and RSA for different things

Comment: Ok. Do you have any idea about 3DES.. do we have to submit t=anything on that?

Comment: I don't know anything for certain, but I don't know why it would be any different.  I think it would be OK.