# Does my ios app use encryption?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, nsurlrequest

I'm developing an iPhone app which edits PDF files.

If I allow users to decrypt the PDF file using a password, do I need to check the "This app contains or incorporates cryptography" checkbox when submitting the app to the app store? The app does not output any encrypted files, simply accepts a password from the user if the file is already encrypted.

Also, one of the ways a user can get a pdf into the app is by supplying a URL, since this URL may be over a https connection, does this makes the app "incorporate cryptography" even if I am just downloading a user requested file into the app and no more. 
And if so, is there a way I can disable https connections and sidestep the issue for now? (I am using NSURLRequest to download the file)

Comment: You might want to check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is answered in the following [well voted thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption). In short, yes if you are using any cypher to decrypt or if you are using https. It is to comply with the US Export regulations.

Comment: You should vote to close the question as a duplicate, instead of linking the original question in an answer.