# Used AES encryption in my app. What should I need to do while uploading

Tags: ios, iphone, aescryptoserviceprovider

I have used AES encryption in my iOS application to encrypt the images and save it to document directory. This is the only task done by my app with the encryption code.

Do I need to select "
Is your product designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?" to YES while uploading.

If YES then Do I need to set YES in second question?

Please Advise. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption

Comment: Do I need to set YES in second question? My App only saves images in encrypted format which user has selected from photos app/takem from camera.