# Does iPhone App using RNCryptor Require any Encryption Registration?

Tags: ios, security, commoncrypto, rncryptor

Does an app posted to the app store using RNCryptor need to register for Export Encryption Registration (ie get an Encryption Registration Number ERN)?

I've removed all the SSL files since I dont use them, it appears the remaining code only uses Apple's CommonCrypto libraries though I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: Yes, you probably need an ERN. Go through the encryption FAQ in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No it does not.

RNCryptor is a AES wrapper, and I use AES (not RNCryptor) in many of my apps without ERN.

None of them had any issues with the App Store review process.

Comment: Sorry but you do need an ERN. Just because you've gotten away with it doesn't mean it is correct. Each developer of an app with encryption must go through the encryption fAQ in iTunes Connect.

Comment: 7 different apps with encryption had more than 30 updates without any issue. Do you think it is "getting away with it" each time? I wish I was that lucky.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Apple's review process. They couldn't care less whether you have encryption or not and whether you correctly indicate that you do or not. It's the government that cares. It's the same as copyright issues. It's not Apple's job to verify whether you violate a copyright or not. That's the developer's job. Go through the encryption FAQ on iTunes Connect. Most likely you will see that your use of encryption actually does require an ERN - as far as the government is concerned. Again, Apple doesn't care.

Comment: I see but, if Apple doesn't care about it, they should not keep asking it on every upload, as it is already mentioned in one of the agreements every dev accepts. And I don't care what government thinks about it. So in practice, I can say you will not have problems with it.

Comment: If your app contains encryption that is not listed as exemption then you *should* register. I can't believe this is the accepted answer.

Comment: Repeating again: This is a perfunctory rule which is never enforced in practice. (in my experience with more than 100 app reviews) It is kind of Maryland prohibiting adultery and imposing $10 fine for it. But if you feel uncomfortable and think it is too much risk for you to take, then good luck with all this: https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Export%20Compliance

Comment: And luckily, they noticed how silly this whole process is, and made some positive changes on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption/40391664#40391664