# Embed YouTube Videos in iOS 9 without https

Tags: http, https, youtube, ios9

I am trying to embed a youtube video in iOS 9 using xcode.

This code all works well:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmv4kEbmWgc")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    youTubeView.loadRequest(request)
```

However, because I dont want to use https because of encryption export issues:
[Does my application "contain encryption"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption)

I am trying a non-http version of the above code:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmv4kEbmWgc")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    youTubeView.loadRequest(request)
```

But that doesnt work.  Anyone know a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that you need to worry about HTTPS urls being classified as encryption.

Comment: http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: Hi Artjom.  This post seems to think I do :-/  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption

Comment: By "non-http", I think you mean "non-httpS". Since you are using iOS 9, I believe it has something to do with "App Transport Security". There's an option to completely turn it off, but I don't suggest doing it at all.

Comment: seems like the web has a lot of contradictory advice on whether https counts as apple export encryption.  I think I contacted apple about this a few months ago - so will have a look and see what I can find.

Comment: @CharlieSeligman I have commented on your question before the answer given by oz solomon....though you have marked his answer correct. Not voted on my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS9 defaults to allowing only HTTPS connections.  Please see answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30739473/862099%20%22this%20Stack%20Overflow%20question%22%20for%20workarounds.) for workarounds.

Specifically for YouTube, all videos are available as HTTPS so I would stick with just HTTPS URLs.