# ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption Cordova Build

Tags: ios, cordova, encryption, app-store-connect

Acknowledging a similar question in the link below does anyone know how to add the information to the config.xml file in Cordova?

[ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption export compliance while internal testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739361/itsappusesnonexemptencryption-export-compliance-while-internal-testing)

I need to have a true value in the plist:

ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption 
ITSEncryptionExportComplianceCode [ Key Value ]

Does anyone know the correct syntax to add this information?

Comment: The screenshot in the post you linked to has the syntax.  
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>

Answer (score 19):

I had to modify Andrej's answer a bit, this worked for me:

```
  <platform name="ios">
    ...
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" mode="add">
      <false/>
    </config-file>
    ...
  </platform>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, also <config-file> seems undocumented in Cordova.

Comment: me to .. added in config.xml and build but it seems not present in plist file\

Comment: This is outdated.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577896/13850 for the current answer.

Answer (score 18):

As of 2/7/2019, the correct way to do this is to add this snippet to your `<platform name="ios">` section:

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="add" target="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption">
    <false/>
</edit-config>
```

Answer (score 13):

I have create a simple empty plugin to set this `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` to false.

Simply add the following to your `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-ios-plugin-no-export-compliance" spec="0.0.5" />
```

or run

```
cordova plugin add cordova-ios-plugin-no-export-compliance
```

If you need to set it to true you can fork the plugin and change the `plugin.xml` file accordingly then add the plugin from the forked repository.

See the [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-ios-plugin-no-export-compliance) on NPM for more info.

Comment: Is that anyway that can be a NPM repository as phonegap builds my plugins via the website?

Comment: You mean the build can't access the github repo? I will check if that's possible

Comment: Found a solution for anyone using phonegap Build, add this to your config.xml, fml stack cant post code in comments lol

Comment: <plugin spec="https://github.com/mikaoelitiana/cordova-plugin-ios-no-export-compliance.git" source="git" />

Answer (score 3):

Note that the plugin mentioned will not work in [phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com). The solution to make this work in phonegap build is [outlined in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966608/adding-custom-parameter-phonegap-build/36496628) and in [this github issue](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/503#issuecomment-207357577): Use

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" mode="add">
  <false/>
</gap:config-file>
```

in your config.xml.

Note that you MUST explicitly set platform="ios" as an attribute, even if you already have a platform block. Note that you MUST use the gap: namespace.

The following WILL NOT work as per 2016-04-08:

```
<platform name="ios">
  <gap:config-file parent="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" mode="add">
    <false/>
  </gap:config-file>
</platform>
```

Neither will this one work:

```
<config-file platform="ios" parent="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" mode="add">
  <false/>
</config-file>
```

Comment: This did not produce any change in the Info.plist file for me.

Comment: Update: Looking at https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/503 I see that this will only work if you are using the Phonegap Build service.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is actually:

```
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption">
    <false/>
</config-file>
```

Taken from [Add hint that this won't work in phonegap build](https://github.com/mikaoelitiana/cordova-plugin-ios-no-export-compliance/issues/1)

Answer (score 1):

November 2019, next is working for me:

```
<platform name="ios">
...
    <config-file parent="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" target="*-Info.plist">
        <false />
    </config-file>
```

NOTE: DON'T FORGET TO REMOVE platforms/ios folder and build again with `ionic cordova prepare ios`. Without that plist file may stay unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append that config in the ***-Info.plist** file, you need to use [config-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file) in this way:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" target="*-Info.plist">
        <false />
    </config-file>
    ....
</platform>
```

The [edit-config](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) is to modify an existing config, and that config doesn't exist by default.

Answer (score 0):

I can across this issue using ionic.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.48
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0
ios-sim version: 5.0.8
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.1.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

After more research than expected I learned that plugins have the ability to update the config.  To that end I just added the plugin   "cordova-plugin-ios-non-exempt-encryption" to my package.json, rebuilt and it works!

Answer (score -1):

This works for me (Actually I needed to put false, instead of true).

```
  <platform name="ios">
    ...
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="CFBundleURLTypes" mode="add">
      <array>
          <dict>
              <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
              <false/>
          </dict>
      </array>
    </config-file>
    ...
  </platform>
```

I am using `cordova 6.3.0` engine`ios@~4.2.0`.

I hope I helped :)