# Is there an info.plist key for advertising identifier use

Tags: ios, info.plist

There is an entry for itsappusesnonexemptencryption ([ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption export compliance while internal testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739361/itsappusesnonexemptencryption-export-compliance-while-internal-testing)), but is there one for the Advertising identifier, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if you find it useful. thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is nothing in the info.plist that's related to Advertising Identifier.

When you will submit the app to the App Store you'll need to check some things in order to inform Apple you are doing usage with the identifier. More details regarding that here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

Here is how to retrieve the Advertising Identifier:

**Objective C -**

@import AdSupport;

...

NSString *adId = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];

**Swift -**

import AdSupport

```
...

let myIDFA: String?
    // Check if Advertising Tracking is Enabled
    if ASIdentifierManager.shared().isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled {
        // Set the IDFA
        myIDFA = ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
    } else {
        myIDFA = nil
    }
```

**(updated to Swift 3.0)**

Answer (score 12):

No, but you can use Felix Krause’s https://fastlane.tools to fully or partially automate whole Delivery process (incl. passing this stupid IDFA Radio Button blocker amongst others).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is out of date.

As of iOS 14, one should now add the [NSUserTrackingUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsusertrackingusagedescription) entry to the info plist in order to access the advertising ID. Otherwise the app crashes with:

```
[access] This app has crashed because it attempted 
to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage 
description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an 
NSUserTrackingUsageDescription key with a string 
value explaining to the user how the app uses this 
data.
```