# Do I need to get an ERN certificate or other for my app?

Tags: ios, https, app-store, app-store-connect

I've come to the "Export Compliance" part of the itunes connect app submission form and although i've been reading different sources on the internet about it for the last few hours i'm still unsure as to what is applicable for my case.
I'm wondering if you can help me gain some clarity on whether I need to get a ERN cert or not or what I need to do.

I've found lots of information but also thinking that it might be outdated so not sure which information to follow:
Note:
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption/40919650#40919650) that since sept 2016 things have changed so it's no longer necessary to get an ERN for https requests. Is this correct?

This is all the encryption I'm using in my app:

1. Using php password_hash() on registration
2. Ajax requests are made to a remote server using https
3. Some requests in the app are made using just http
   (eg. requests using the phonegap file-transfer to upload photos) to a remote server.

My app is for users to communicate with each other and ajax requests are made for things like submitting comments and submitting a contact form.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Your best option is to read Apple's FAQ: https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq?group=managing-your-apps_trade-compliance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739361/itsappusesnonexemptencryption-export-compliance-while-internal-testing/36028077#36028077