# Missing export compliance information - iTunes Connect/TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I play the “Developer” user role in my iTunes Connect team. And I uploaded TestFlight build to the account. 
Now I can see the build I uploaded under TestFlight tab. But, there’s this warning as follows,

[image: Image 1 here]

And after I uploaded the build it gave me this warning without the success message.

[image: Image 2 here]

Why am I getting these issues?
Do these issues relate to each other? 
And any idea how to solve these issues?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, you need to set this flag in your plist... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739361/itsappusesnonexemptencryption-export-compliance-while-internal-testing

Comment: The 2nd issue is unrelated to the first. It appears the team id for the build has changed.

Comment: thanks for the feedback!

Comment: the previous build was uploaded with full access, not with the "Developer" user role
can it be the reason for the change of team id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I found myself, for the first issue user role doesn't matter. What you have to there is go inside you build and "Provide Export Compliance Information". There you have to provide security information regarding your app. Once you finished answering the questions you will be able to start internal testing.

Comment: Hi can u plz help me? I am facing same issue where we can add this information?

Comment: At today, from Xcode, inside project or target build configuration, the pointed out option seems to be missing.

Answer (score 4):

You should add a Boolean to your info.plist "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption" set to False

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
<false/>
```