# ERROR ITMS-90592 "Invalid Export Compliance Code" when uploading to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

In order to avoid the manual export compliance form each time we upload a new version of our apps, I tried to include the ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption key in the Info.plist, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739361/itsappusesnonexemptencryption-export-compliance-while-internal-testing). (In fact the app uses cordova, but as far as I see, the entry made it correctly into the plist.)

However, we I now try to upload the app, I got:

> ERROR ITMS-90592 "Invalid Export Compliance Code. The export
>   compliance key value in the app's Info.plist doesn't match the key
>   value of the app's export compliance documentation. To find the
>   correct value, go to My Apps on App Store Connect."
>
> An unknown error occurred.

Of course, the error description could be less verbose, but I miss the information where to look in App Store Connect for the correct entry.

Any suggestion?

When googling for the error code, I only find different descriptions associated with it.

(As our app uses https, I think we have to set ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption to true / YES. And provide the self classification report.)

Answer (score 13):

My app uses encryption and the key defined in plist  was mismatched by the key provided by App Store Connect.

[image]

Now, The question is how to get the key from App Store Connect? Here the doc has mentioned clearly [here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev0dc15d044)

> If your app uses encryption, you may be required to provide export
> compliance documentation in App Store Connect. If your build doesn’t
> use encryption, you specify this information in Xcode.
>
> You upload the export compliance document and submit it for review
> using App Store Connect, as described in Provide export compliance
> documentation for encryption in App Store Connect Help. Once the
> document is approved, App Store Connect will provide key-value pairs
> that you can add to the information property list (Info.plist) in your
> Xcode project. App Review
>
> If you provide the export compliance information in the build, then
> you don’t need to provide this information later when you distribute
> your app using TestFlight or submit it to the App Store.
>
> In the Project navigator (), choose the target, then click Info.
>
> In the last row of the target properties table, click the Add button
> (+).
>
> In the search field, enter the export compliance key followed by the
> Return character and set its value.
>
> If your app is not using encryption, add the App Uses Non-Exempt
> Encryption (ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption) key and set the value to
> NO.
>
> If your app uses encryption, add the App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption
> (ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption) key and set the value to YES.
>
> If your app requires export compliance, add the App Encryption Export
> Compliance Code (ITSEncryptionExportComplianceCode) key and enter the
> value for this key provided by App Store Connect.

Go to App Store Connect -> **My Apps** -> **Services tab** then Choose **Encryptionthen** click on iOS Documentation button and provide the appropriate info. After uploading the doc Apple will review and if everything is fine then Apple will provide the key as shown in image below. Add that key in your info.plist file.

[image]

Comment: No it's in App Store Connect -> Apps -> YourApp -> Services tab

Comment: @DDS is correct. They must have changed it. You should consider updating your answer to reflect the new menu.

Comment: I have no encryption info in Services tab. Only Game Center and Promo Codes