# Core Data or NSUserDefaults to avoid manipulation of the user?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, core-data

What is the best way to save data (e.g. passwords) which the user **can't** manipulate or see? `NSUserDefaults` are getting saved in a file on the Mac which the user **can** manipulate and see. How about `Core Data`? Is this also saved in a file or is there a way that the user can see the `Core Data`?

Comment: use the keychain - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: Yes, core-data files can be accessed easily. The best solution is to encrypt  the data you need hidden.

Comment: there's a great wrapper for the keychain https://cocoapods.org/pods/SSKeychain

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NSUserDefaults definitely shouldn't be used to store passwords because it is stored in plain text. Core data can be encrypted, but it isn't by default. It stores all of its data in a SQLite database which is really easy to read. Passwords should be stored in the system Keychain. The keychain can be accessed with the [Security Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security).

There are several libraries out there that make using the keychain much easier, eg: [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith) or [Valet](https://github.com/square/Valet).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @esthepiking's suggestion to use Keychain, be aware that implementing your own encryption to store passwords might create obligations for you to provide more paperwork under the App Store's "Export Compliance" requirements.   See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption).

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html) to get the example to use ios Keychain Services to store and retrieve user name and password securely