# iTunes Export Compliance and HTTPS

Tags: encryption, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

iTunes Export Compliance and HTTPS

Hello Guys,

I recently uploaded an app to Appstore and it's still in review process. Meanwhile I came across "Export Compliance" under features in My App. It basically asks me, if I have used any kind of encryption in my application. If used, it asks me to provide Export Compliance Documents.
I haven't used any explicit encryption in my application. But I am calling few web-service calls using https protocol. I know that https protocol sends data encrypted. In this case, do I need to upload Export Compliance documents? Or can set Export Compliance to NO in my iTunes for this app?

Comment: Short answer: No
Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020531/switching-from-http-to-https-in-ios-app-brings-up-export-compliance-issues-when

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching from http to https in iOS App brings up Export Compliance issues when publishing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020531/switching-from-http-to-https-in-ios-app-brings-up-export-compliance-issues-when)