# Am I using encryption?

Tags: java, ios, ssl, encryption, ionic-framework

I have developed a mobile app and would like to deploy it to Apples App Store. However, before I do so, I need to state if my app uses encryption or not.

[image]

Before I submit this I would just like to get some advise please.

I do look at my app in `Chrome's Developer Tools`, and check all network traffic. All requests are `http` and none are `https`. Except I do use Firebase-Authentication, and it uses `https`.

e.g.

```
Request URL:https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**Question**

Does this mean my app does use encryption?

Excuse me if this is an obvious question, but I am a little confused because I am making use of a Firebase-Authentication service that makes `https` calls. My api doesn't make the calls, rather a 3rd party api my app uses does.

**UPDATE**

It looks like I am making use of encryption due to Firebase Auth, but due to the fact that I only use encryption for authentication I qualify for exemption:

[image]

Still confused... If I qualify for exemption, do I still need to report this to the US Government as stated above by Apple?

The reason I ask ask, is due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption/40919650#40919650).

**Question**

Do I still need to report this to the US Government? Are there any other app developers out there who have been through this process? How do you report this to the US Government?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your app uses encryption. Did you click the "learn more" link and see what it says?

Comment: This is the Learn More link. It doesn't seem to be very clear:  https://www.bis.doc.gov/informationsecurity2016-updates

Comment: I have also read here that reporting encryption is no longer required. But then why is Apple asking for this info and stating that it needs to be reported to the US Government?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40391664/776167 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption/40919650#40919650

Comment: And you *should switch* to HTTPS. It provides massive benefits for relatively little cost.

Comment: @chrylis thank you, good advise. However, my issue is I am on a tight budget, and I host my server on AWS. In order to introduce `https`, you need to use AWS Load Balancing, can't be done on a normal free-tier server unfortunately.

Comment: @Richard Assuming you're using EC2, that's not true.

Comment: @Aehmlo, I have read that a Load Balancer is requires for https on AWS. Glad to hear it's not the case. I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk running a Tomcat Server with RESTful Java services. Do you have any links to material on how I can implement https?

Comment: https://melo.myds.me/wordpress/lets-encrypt-for-tomcat-7-on-ds/

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help. I also found the following. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html

Comment: Your app use encryption according to that definition. Also, I thought I read somewhere that the app store will soon reject any app that makes http connections: they all have to be https.