# iTunesConnect requires me to submit "year-end self qualification report"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This has popped up when I tried to submit my app for testing

> If you are making use of ATS or making a call to HTTPS please note
>   that you are required to submit a year-end self classification report
>   to the US government

The answer is yes, I do make calls to https to talk to my API.

What exactly should I do to satisfy this requirement?

What is a year-end self qualification report?

Comment: Looks like this might helpful for you: http://tigelane.blogspot.in/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption/40919650#40919650   the comment above mine provides a link from 2011 and is outdated info, all you have to do is submit the year-end self qualification report

Answer (score 2):

This report is better known as "Annual Self Classification Report". It concerns a CSV file with information of your apps that use encryption in whatever way. This report must be formatted in a specific way and send to crypt-supp8@bis.doc.gov and enc@nsa.gov each year.

Some very helpful information can be found in this article:

- http://simonfairbairn.com/bis-year-end-self-classification-report/

Or directly at the Bureau of Industry, if you like bureaucratic prose:

- https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/encryption-faqs/15-policy-guidance/encryption/261-reporting#Two

The Bureau of Industry tend to change their website and links on a regular basis, so maybe this link opens a 'not found' page.

Comment: Is this required for everyone, globally, or is it only for US? As I am from South Africa, I am just wondering after I saw this...

Comment: According to Apple's docs, "Apps uploaded to App Store Connect are uploaded to an Apple server in the United States. When you submit your app with the intention of distributing your app on the App Store or to external testers through TestFlight outside of the U.S. or Canada, it is considered a U.S. export and is subject to U.S. export laws (regardless of where your legal entity is based)."
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev88f5c7bf9

Comment: Hey, I've just sent the annual export compliance. Approximately how long does it take before they answer so that I can upload it to upload it to apple so that the app can get published? thanks

Comment: @Mattias I never received an response to my annual export compliances

Comment: @Ely I'm confused, for me it says "To make your app available on the App Store, you must submit a copy of your U.S. Commodity Classification Automated Tracking System (CCATS) approval from the U.S. Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS" and then it wants me to attach a file, how do I get through this if they never respond? :/

Comment: Okay thanks a lot it's working now, I answered no on a question where I was supposed to answer yes!