# iTune Connect: Export Compliance

Tags: app-store-connect, qr-code, itunes

One of my features of my app is that one can compose a text message and convert it into a QR code to share with others.

In preparing to submit my app to the Apple Store, one of the questions that Apple ask me is:

> **Export Compliance**
>
> Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or
>   incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only
>   utilizing the encryption available within Apple’s operating system.)

I am little confused how to answer this question. Has anyone submitted an app using QR code?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello! Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855629/export-compliance-in-ios-app-submission

Comment: A QR code is not *encryption*.