# Does Admob count as using encryption in an app

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, admob

I am uploading a build of my app, and apple is asking if it uses encryption. I'm not sure if AdMob or Firebase counted as encryption and if I needed to follow the ERN process. Thank you.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice.

Based on [this article](https://pupeno.com/2015/12/15/legally-submit-app-apples-app-store-uses-encryption-obtain-ern/), it sounds like you should.

All communications with Google and Firebase through Google-provided SDKs use the SSL libraries provided by Apple to communicate with their respective services.  If you're making requests to AdMob and retrieving ad images, your communicating over an encrypted channel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you think it might be exempt under category 5 part 2 of Us Export Regulations, as Apple mentions you don’t have to file an ern under such conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed google privacy policy and it said: "We use encryption to keep your data private when it is moved"
https://policies.google.com/privacy#infosecurity

Firebase:
Data encryption
For the collected end-user data listed on this page, Firebase encrypts the data in transit using HTTPS.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/play-data-disclosure

AdMob:
All of the user data collected by Google Mobile Ads SDK is encrypted in transit using the Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol.
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/play-data-disclosure