# Export Compliance iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, braintree

This Apple Export Compliance is very confusing.
I have an app developed in Ionic framework. It is there in Appstore for the past 3 years. When tried to update the app, Apple is asking all these questions.

In my app, I am using

- HTTPS for all server communication
- Braintree client-side encryption for encrypting the Credi card info [https://developers.braintreepayments.com/deprecated/client-side-encryption/javascript-library]

What should I answer these questions?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Thanks,
Girish

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does my application "contain encryption"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption)