# Do i need to answer yes when confirming the encryption in the app store?

Tags: encryption, app-store, app-store-connect, appsflyer, moengage

I'm using AES and Hash SHA256 to encrypt password in my swift apps.

Also, i call "HTTPS" for some WebView inside my apps using .

I got problem when try to submit my apps. Should i say yes to confirm encryption when i upload my apps to App Store?

Also i use some pods (e.g. MoEngage, AppsFlyer, advance.ai(liveness)) and i don't know if there is other encryption there.

This Apps is created in INA not USA or Canada (Care about self classification report)

**EDIT**

Should i just follow the link below ?

https://www.cocoanetics.com/2017/02/itunes-connect-encryption-info/#respond

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does my application "contain encryption"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135081/does-my-application-contain-encryption)

Comment: i don't really understand, whats the meaning of ("only makes call(s) over http")

Comment: As in only using the built-in HTTPS library, not encrypting the information with another algorithm

Comment: then, even i don't encrypt the information. I need to say yes to the encryption ?   i edit my post (add link on it) should i just follow that post? @Martheen

Comment: Yes to all question, including your updated link. I'd like to add that even if you're developing in INA and sell to INA, technically your app is still exported from the US https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev88f5c7bf9 which is why you need to state the seemingly useless statement